# Getting blank UFT screen during test run

Tags: hp-uft

I am performing web application automation testing. I am getting "resources are running low" on UFT during test run. My script does take screenprint during test run. When I executed my script, UFT screen went blank and then UFT took screenprint of UFT's blank screen instead of taking browser screenprint. I restarted the machine and cleared out the browser cash. I still have the same issue. How can I fix the low resources issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: `How can I fix the low resources issue?`... Keep everything closed except for UFT and juice up your system.

Comment: Everything is always closed. During test run, UFT opens multiple excel files, word files, browsers. Then UFT goes blank.

Comment: How abt your system specs?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, RAM 16GB, 64 bit OS, Intel CPU 2.60 GHz, UFT 14, Chrome

Comment: That's great specs. How abt space? You said `UFT opens multiple excel files, word files, browsers`... Can you handle those files one at time or as less as possible?

Comment: Upvoted for the great screenshot :)

Comment: I added another image. If you know why that happens, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Try to update the graphics card driver.
2. If installed, then uninstall capture driver (menu: option - screen capture), if not, install it.
3. If saving movie of run session, try running without it.
4. Verify that you are clearing all objects, E.g. set xxx=Nothing (especially if using global objects, and re-assigning them every iteration).
5. Check Uft memory during run, you might find that it is being loaded on specific code run.
6. Check available Ram during run, your machine might face low resources due to heavy tasks running.